# Azure Data Factory v2 Oracle on-premise to SQL Server (IaaS)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a ADF v2 pipeline that will copy data from on-premise Oracle server to SQL Server VM. 
Network Admins have set up Integration Runtime for Oracle. Their idea was that we can simply use SQL Azure as a target. It worked, but for some other reason, we want to use SQL Server on VM instead. 
I figured that I need to set up stand-alone IR and set it on VM. Unfortunately, when I tried to run pipeline I got the error that both source and target need to be on the same IR.

Comment: I dont think you are describing your problem correctly, could you please show what do you have, what works and where is the error?

Comment: A single self-hosted integration runtime can be used for multiple on-premises data sources, can you paste the the exact error message please?

Comment: I think he has an on premise IR for the Oracle server, and needs another one in the vm for the Sql Server, but I'd like more info.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that source and target should be on the same self-hosted IR, so that the Copy activity could be executed on that IR. You can learn more details on how Copy activity work in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview.

For your case:

- If your **IR for Oracle** can access the target SQL Server VM, you can just use that IR to copy data from Oracle to SQL Server.
- Else, you need 2 copy activities: (1) copy from Oracle to a data store that both source Oracle VM and target SQL Server VM can access (e.g. a Blob Storage) on **IR for Oracle**. (2) copy from Blob to SQL Server on **IR for SQL Server**